# Set addRowsAPIEnabled = true for imported datasets from PBIX within Power BI API

Tags: api, import, powerbi

I have used the Power BI API to import my PBIX project to Power BI service via this method: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/upload-a-local-pbix-file-using-the-import-api/

Everything works fine (*it uploaded corresponding dataset and report to the Power BI service*), but now I am not able to AddRow to the imported dataset.

This is what i get from GetDatasets method: [image]. You can see that there is attribute "addRowsAPIEnabled = false".

Is it anyhow possible to enable the attribute to be able to AddRows to the imported dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is still not available to use API method AddRows to datasets which were not created via API as well.

Anyways, hopefully it should be available soon according this: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/268152-developer-apis/suggestions/6912162-push-data-via-api-into-an-existing-model